# show jtable on button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to show table , dynamically fill the row data in a for loop and show , this on button click.
Here is my code, can somebody help me please.

```
public class GetQuotes {

    private JTextField wtField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField htField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField lnField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField wiField = new JTextField(10);
    final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,3));
    JPanel labelFields = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));
    JTable table;
    JPanel guiCenter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,3));
    //default constructor
    public GetQuotes(){

    labelFields.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Enter Inputs"));

    JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,1,1));
    //labels.setBorder(new TitledBorder("GridLayout"));
    JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,1,1));

     labels.add(new JLabel("Weight"));
     labels.add(new JLabel("Length"));
     labels.add(new JLabel("Width"));
     labels.add(new JLabel("Height"));

     fields.add(wtField);
     fields.add(lnField);
     fields.add(wiField);
     fields.add(htField);

      labelFields.add(labels,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      labelFields.add(fields,BorderLayout.EAST);


     JPanel buttonConstrsint = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
     JButton getQuotesButton = new JButton("Get Quotes..");

      getQuotesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                   Quote[] data = getData();

                    table = new JTable(generateTableModel(data));
                    table.setModel(generateTableModel(data));

                    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
                    guiCenter.add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                    gui.add(guiCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);


               }

            }
        });

    buttonConstrsint.add(getQuotesButton);
    guiCenter.add(buttonConstrsint,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    gui.add(labelFields,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    gui.add(guiCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);


    }

    private Quote[] getData(){

        //this function returns the needed data

    }

    //test the class
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new GetQuotes();
            }
        });

        }

    public static TableModel generateTableModel(Quote[] dataa) {

        String[][] data = new String[100][2] ;
          String[] colNames = {"col1","col2"};

        //here how to add another column data  dataa[j].getPrice 
          for(int i=0; i<colNames.length; i++){
          for(int j=0; j<dataa.length; j++){
              data[j][i] = dataa[j].getServiceName();

          }
          }

        return new DefaultTableModel(data, colNames);
    }
}
```

1) I need help in filling rowData in for loop in generateTableModel function. At the moment I can fill single column data, how to build the second column data.

2) once table constructed here and returned back to actionperformed function above, where I'm adding table to jscrollpanel and to the guicenterpanel.
But somehow that doesn't show the table.

can somebody help me please.

Comment: You have posted much unrelated code. When I am trying to do something new and complex, I usually create a small program completely separate from my larger project just for the purposes of demonstrating if what I am trying to do can be done by me, or if not, at least isolating my errors so others can better help me. I suggest that you try doing the same -- creating a new program without any code unrelated to your current problem, but just demonstrates your best effort to solve the current problem. Then if still stuck, post this smaller manageable program for us to review and assist.

Comment: It's not a good practice to change Swing layouts dynamically. Instead I would add an empty `JTable` during initialization, and fill in the data (possibly by `setTableModel()` and/or `fireTableStractureChanged()`), and maybe also use a `CardLayout` to hide the empty table till it's needed.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

```
table = new JTable(generateTableModel(data));
// table.setModel(generateTableModel(data));  // *** this is redundant

JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
guiCenter.add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

gui.add(guiCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);

// don't forget to revalidate and repaint your container:
gui.revalidate();
gui.repaint();
```

Get rid of the redundant line of code, and don't forget to revalidate and repaint the container after adding or removing components.

---

Regarding:

> 1) I need help in filling rowData in for loop in generateTableModel function. At the moment I can fill single column data, how to build the second column data.

I'm not sure that we have enough information to allow us to answer this. What does your current code do? Does it create a two column JTable? What is it filled with? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: gui.revalidate() worked fine. I found solution to fill the table with two column data. Now I can see only one row of data and if i move the up and down arrow keys I can see data, I can't re-size the frame, also how to make this table size bigger , I added table.setsize didn't work. Can you suggest where it is going wrong

Comment: @DarkStar: you've a new problem and possibly need a new question here. For us to best be able to answer this, you'll want to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).